# Disabling double click works on Firefox, but does not work on Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, forms, button

I need to prevent double click in a asp.net button, when the form is posted.

I have tried the following jQuery code:

```
        $(this).submit(function () {
            $('.btn').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        });
```

And it works in Firefox browser, but not in Chrome.

Here is the HTML of my asp.net button:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="reset-password.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div class="orangeBTN">
    <input type="button" name="ctl00$ctl00$content$content$btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ctl00$content$content$btnSubmit&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="ctl00_ctl00_content_content_btnSubmit" class="btn pri" />
</div>
</form>
```

Is there a simple method that I can use that will be universal?

For your help, many thanks.

**UPDATE I**

I am including the .aspx html, and the JavaScript that now seem to work for me.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlInput" CssClass="pnlInput" runat="server">
    <fieldset id="resetPassRight">
        <asp:Panel ID="pButtons" runat="server" CssClass="buttons">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn pri" runat="server" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </fieldset>
</asp:Panel>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.pnlInput fieldset .btn').one('click', function () {
        $(this).trigger("click");
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE II**

Below there is the jQuery code that I ended up using. So far I think it works.

```
        /** Start - This jQuery will disable double click */
        $('.pnlInput fieldset .btn').one('click', function () {
            $(this).trigger("click");
            $(this).attr("disabled", 'disabled');               
        });
        /** End - This jQuery will disable double click */
```

One of the reasons jQuery was not executing was the fact that the asp button has a property of:

```
UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

And this was preventing the client code to be evaluated correctly across different browsers.

Comment: what is `this` in the jQuery code?

Comment: Is not how the form gets passed to the function?

Comment: From the code snippet above, `this` could be anything. Apart from that, and assuming that `this` is the form, the input would need a type of `submit` to trigger the submit function, but it has a `button` type

Comment: does the new code you posted in the update work correctly?

Comment: Hi Alvaro, so far I think it does. I am also doing other tests and so I have not been able to complete my testing thoroughly and accept an answer to complete the question. I will do that as soon as I am done.

Comment: If it does, you should add your update as an answer (indicating the `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` thing) and mark it as the correct one. Good luck with the testing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input has a `type="button"` it will not trigger the submit function (not even on FF, or at least I was not able to get it), as you can see on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ye9921e/ (replaced the target with an empty function to avoid errors)

If you change the input to have `type="submit"`, then the submit function will be triggered and the button will be disabled. You can see it on this other fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ye9921e/1/

So, just change the input to a `submit`, and then the onsubmit event will be triggered.

Comment: The asp button had a property: UseSubmitBehavior="false". I removed it and seems it is working. I will add the code I use in the end, perhaps it needs corrections.

Comment: one thing: pnlInput is an id so the selector should be `#pnlInput fieldset .btn` (right now you have it as if it was a class)

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it would. I'm a dodo and didn't see it. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You may try .attr() instead of .prop()

Comment: "The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method." - http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

It's works in my case. The __doPostBack( $(this).attr('name'), '') needs for Chrome.

```
 <asp:Button ID="Btn_AjouterFichier" runat="server" Text="Ajouter photo" CssClass="singleclick" />

$('.singleclick').click(function () {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        __doPostBack( $(this).attr('name'), '')
});
```